# Can anyone add a 'remi' tag

Tags: support, tags

Since I don't have enough reputation, someone else coud do it: add a tag for questions regarding the [remi repository](https://blog.remirepo.net/). I would name the tag 'remi'.

If I search for remi, I get 135 results. So IMO it has some relevance.

Comment: But what kind of question would be _specific_ to that particular repository as opposed to being about repositories in general? I can only think of questions about what packages are there, which should really be addressed to the maintainer, and issues about its private key etc, which hardly seems to merit its own tag.

Comment: Glancing at the results of searching for ["remi"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=remi) doesn't show anything that's specific to the repo. Only questions asked by people using the repo. I don't really see why we'd need a tag for it. Nobody (except Remi, presumably) would be an expert on the repo itself.

Comment: @terdon Ok, I see. I just thought it would make sense to group those questions a bit. But you may be right. If others see it like you then my request can be deleted.

Comment: No! No reason to delete it! It is a useful discussion to have around. And, as you say, maybe others will disagree. Either way, thank you for starting the discussion.

Comment: Ok. Though your objection makes sense. For me it was just a way of grouping those questions, to see, what was already asked. Maybe, to ultimatly find out that searching for those question with a tag doesn't help me anyway... :-D